# How can I figure out what progress InnoDB is making after a huge INSERT completes?

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, innodb

I'm using MariaDB: `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.32-MariaDB`. The only configuration option I have changed from Ubuntu's default is that I changed `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1G` after having some issues with deleting a large number of rows before. I don't have replication set up.

I just inserted roughly 600 million rows into a table. All my tables are InnoDB except, of course, the system tables. The table (`edges`) is really simple; two integer columns which form a composite primary key. The insertion process took approximately 4 days and completed successfully (it was an `INSERT INTO edges SELECT some, columns FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.column = b.foreign_key`).

During the INSERT, I had an idea of how many rows would be inserted, so to get a rough idea of progress I would start a separate `mysql` query prompt and run `SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` followed by `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM the_table` and find how many rows have been inserted so far. I also ran `SHOW PROCESSLIST` which just shows how long it's been running. I was able to figure out a rough estimate of how long things were going to take by doing some math: taking the number of seconds the query had been running from SHOW PROCESSLIST and extrapolating that based on the rough number of rows inserted so far and how many rows I thought would result.

Here is where I am a bit lost: Once the prompt where I inserted the rows returned successfully, the load average spiked higher than it was during the INSERT. I see that it's all because of IO from MySQL.

[image: htop output]

`SHOW PROCESSLIST` doesn't really say anything, even though clearly some processes are running on several different threads as indicated by `htop`.

[image: show processlist]

The closest I've gotten to figure out what's going on is `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`. Here's some log-related data:

[image: show engine innodb status logs]

It seems like the large numbers keep increasing, but I am confused because it says `0 pending log flushes`, yet `Log flushed up to` keeps increasing, and no queries at all are running.

Here is the `INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX`, but

[image: insert buffer and adaptive hash index]

Here's the output in gist form: https://gist.github.com/hut8/3508c901e6ebfaab65656b8ae3c32ae3

`CREATE TABLE` for the table into which insertion is happening:

```sql
 CREATE TABLE `edges` (                                                         
    `source_page_id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL,                                             
    `dest_page_id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL,                                               
    PRIMARY KEY (`source_page_id`,`dest_page_id`))
```

The insert statement was:

```sql
INSERT INTO edges (source_page_id, dest_page_id)
     SELECT pl.pl_from, v.page_id
       FROM pagelinks pl
 INNER JOIN vertexes v
         ON v.page_title = pl.pl_title;
```

The two tables that are the source for the data in that join look like:

```sql
 CREATE TABLE `pagelinks` ( 
`pl_from` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,      
`pl_namespace` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,                 
`pl_title` varbinary(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',         
`pl_from_namespace` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0  
 )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=binary ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;

CREATE TABLE `vertexes` ( 
`page_id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,                              
`page_title` varbinary(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',                         
PRIMARY KEY (`page_id`),  
KEY `page_title_index` (`page_title`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

There are no indexes on `pagelinks` as you can see.

```
MariaDB [wiki]> explain SELECT pl.pl_from, v.page_id
FROM pagelinks pl
INNER JOIN vertexes v
ON v.page_title = pl.pl_title\G
*************************** 1. row *************************** 
id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: pl
type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
key: NULL 
key_len: NULL
ref: NULL
rows: 676208507 
Extra: 
*************************** 2. row *************************** 
id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: v
type: ref
possible_keys: page_title_index 
key: page_title_index
key_len: 257
ref: wiki.pl.pl_title
rows: 1
Extra: Using index
```

Basically, I am very confused as to what the server is actually doing, and how long it will take to do it. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Again, I am only wondering about what happens after the INSERT appears to have completed. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each relevant table.  I need to see the exact indexes, exact datatypes, etc.  Also provide the `SELECT` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: Hey Rick, I added what you asked for. Thanks for your time and expertise.

Comment: If those `INT(8)` values are never more than 16M, use `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED`, which is 3 bytes instead of `INT` which is 4 bytes.  Meanwhile, the `(8)` is irrelevant and ignored.

Comment: @Hut8 From root login, at MySQL Command Prompt, SHOW GLOBAL STATUS WHERE variable_name LIKE '%dirty%';  will reveal current 'in-flight' volume of data to be RECORDED to your tables.  BYTES and PAGE counts involved.  When zeros reported, system is caught up with your INSERT completion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

InnoDB is designed to postpone costly I/O work in various ways. When you write changes to rows in a transaction, it only modifies pages in RAM -- in the buffer pool. But it also logs the change in the InnoDB redo log on disk, so it can recover if a crash occurs. Then the pages in the buffer pool are flushed to disk some time later.

But if you are writing 600 million rows, you're certainly going to fill up the redo log over and over. When that happens, InnoDB is forced to flush modified pages from RAM to disk immediately.

In addition to that, building secondary indexes is postponed further. That's the "Insert buffer" noted in the innodb status. So a transaction is committed, data pages are flushed later, and secondary index pages are "merged" later still.

Basically, there's a lot of cleanup work to do after you do a lot of inserts/updates. That's why you continue to see I/O load for some time after you think your inserts are done.

The InnoDB design is sensible if the high write rate is sporadic. It tries to react very quickly, and defer some of the work. Hoping it can "catch up" before you have another surge of writes. But you're trying to do a four-day long surge, so InnoDB ends up falling further and further behind. Once things quiet down, it has to do a great deal of flushing and index merges before it's truly done.

How can you monitor progress? The means to do that is not developed well. Normally you don't have to monitor it. You can query the innodb metrics this way:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_METRICS WHERE NAME LIKE '%ibuf%';
```

But it seems that the insert buffer monitor is disabled by default (all the ibuf-related metrics show `status: disabled` in my MySQL 8.0 instance). Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-information-schema-metrics-table.html to learn how to enable specific innodb monitors.

Interpreting the results of these innodb metrics is a little mysterious. You can read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-change-buffer.html but you will have to "read between the lines" quite a bit to understand what the numbers represent. You may even need to read some of the source code of the InnoDB storage engine.

Answer (score 3):

Run `SHOW PROCESSLIST` with suitable permissions -- you can see only the commands that you are allowed to see.

Load average and I/O may vary for a lot of reasons.  `UNIQUE` indexes are checked and updated on the fly; non-unique indexes are inserted later (cf "change buffering").  This *may* explain the spike *after* the Insert returned.  It's not something to worry about.

How tiny is your server (or VM)?  1G for the buffer pool implies that there will be a lot of I/O for 600M rows.

"Progress bars" are only partially viable.

Will you be reloading the 600M rows frequently?  If so, we can discuss better ways.  Is this a complete replacement of a table?  Or are most rows the same?  Or what?

A big cost in inserting 600M rows at once is the need to be read to `ROLLBACK` the entire transaction.  Once it is `COMMITted`, all the "rollback" stuff needs to be cleaned up.  This may be part of your post-commit spike.

If other connections are touching the table, this big Insert is likely to run slower than if they were not touching it.

> I will only periodically replace all the rows and will never update them. I am getting the data directly from Wikipedia's dumps and don't need the most up to date data. I could insert with no primary key and then build it later, or just add an index on the first column because that's all I will query by.

Assuming you are getting a CSV file, do it this way:

1. `CREATE TABLE new_tbl ...` -- With the `PRIMARY KEY` in place.
2. Use the OS's sort to sort the csv file in PK order.
3. `LOAD DATA INFILE ...` into `new_tbl`.
4. `RENAME TABLE tbl TO old_tbl, new_tbl TO tbl;`
5. `DROP TABLE tbl`;

Notes:

- Swapping is terrible for performance; since you have only 2GB of RAM, lower `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to only 500M.
- You probably need to be using utf8mb4 everywhere.  (But I guess that does not matter, since I see `VARBINARY`.
- `ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED` may not be worth it.
- Steps 1,4,5 are virtually instantaneous.
- The sort may be the fastest possible way to do the sort.
- By having the data pre-sorted, populating the PK will be virtually free.
- There will be essentially no downtime because step 4 is very fast.
- No need for "progress bar"
- Since the load is essentially "sequential", it does not matter that the buffer_pool is much less than the table size.
- By building a fresh table, there is less "Rollback/undo/redo/etc" stuff to deal with.
- "There are no indexes on pagelinks as you can see." -- No index is needed since it will scan the table entirely anyway.

Chunking the `INSERT...SELECT`:

Assuming that the 4-day Insert is really being slowed down by that `JOIN`, Let's chunk up the query.  That is, let's walk through `pagelinks` 1000 rows at a time, then `COMMIT`.  That will involve 1000 lookups in `vertexes` 1000 times (nearly 1000 16KB blocks fetched = 16MB).  This periodic Commit helps soften the overhead discussed by Bill.  See this for tips on chunking: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks

Comment: Is it an option to insert all 600 million rows in the table without the primary key? Then after all data is inserted, create the primary key?

Comment: @TheImpaler - Let me see the `CREATE TABLE` after the PK and other indexes have been added.

Comment: I ran `SHOW PROCESSLIST` as root and I got the same result. I added the additional info you requested. I will only periodically replace all the rows and will never update them. I am getting the data directly from Wikipedia's dumps and don't need the most up to date data. I could insert with no primary key and then build it later, or just add an index on the first column because that's all I will query by.

Comment: The server has 2 GB of RAM and two processors.

Comment: @Hut8 - Not a problem, but see the details I just added.  (If it is not CSV, let me know how it is formatted and I will modify my Answer.)  Also, is the PK numeric or alphabetic?

Comment: @Hut8 - Now that I am staring at the table definitions...  Do you load all tables but `edges` fast enough?  But then that `INSERT...SELECT` is what is taking 4 days?

Comment: @Hut8 - Not a dumb question; a challenging one.  Alas, much of my answers do not directly address that Insert..Select.  (I did not downvote it.)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect 98% of the Select's JOIN is due to I/O that cannot be cached.  It would take a lot more RAM to provide a big enough buffer_pool to 'solve' that problem.

So, here's **Plan B**:

Add another column to `vertexes` (after loading):

```
CREATE TABLE `vertexes` ( 
`page_id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,                              
`page_title` varbinary(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',   
title_hash BINARY(16) NOT NULL,  -- MD5 of the title                      
PRIMARY KEY (`page_id`),  
KEY `page_title_index` (`page_title`),
INDEX(title_hash, page_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Similarly, have the `title_hash` in the other table.  Now, change the `JOIN` to act on `title_hash` instead of `page_title` -- a much smaller value.  Hence, it caches better.

PS.  MariaDB 10.3 *may* have a mechanism for doing that hashing automatically.

But, that may not be good enough, so here's **Plan C:**

Let's arrange for the `JOIN` to act on the two tables in the "same order".  (This starts from the original tables, no hashing.)  That is:

SELECT pl.pl_from, v.page_id
FROM pagelinks pl
INNER JOIN vertexes v
ON v.page_title = pl.pl_title;

If we have these two pairs *sorted*, the JOIN will work like a zipper:

```
(pl_title, pl_from)
(page_title, page_id)
```

That can easily be done by having

```
INDEX(pl_title, pl_from)
INDEX(page_title, page_id)  -- This already exists.
```

Now, the JOIN will (should) use those two indexes, both of which are in alphabetical order, thereby making the work very efficient (wrt I/O).

Summary of Plan C:

- `ALTER TABLE pagelinks ADD INDEX(page_title, page_id);`
- Add `ORDER BY pl_title` to the `SELECT` to make them go in the same order.
- Leave off the PK on `edges` during the Insert; instead do `ALTER TABLE edges ADD PRIMARY KEY(source_page_id, dest_page_id)` after loading the table.